# Using match expression in nested for loop

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I seem to lose intellisense within the query of the innermost for loop, which is leading me to believe that I am writing bad code. It appears to be an issue with the match statement.  When I try to match by simply capturing the value everything seems to work.  When I try to match by comparing values the code seems to break. Here is the code:

```
let createOrderFromStdOrder () =

    // retrieve standard orders
    let stdOrders = 
        Queries.retrieveStdOrders null |> Seq.toList

    // retrieve orders
    let orders = Queries.retrieveOrders null |> Seq.toList

    // current date
    let curDate = DateTime.Now

    // iterate and create order
    for i in stdOrders do

        let validDates = MyUtil.stdDeadlineCheck i

        // process standard order
        let orderDate = 
            if not validDates.IsEmpty then
                let daysOfWeek = 
                    query{
                        for row in validDates do
                        sortBy row
                        take 2
                    }

                for j in daysOfWeek do
                    match j with
                    | c -> // this seems to work
                        let order =
                            query{
                                for o in orders do
                                where(o.Works = i.Works) // and I get dot intellisense o and i
                            }
```

but if I try to match like this it seems to break:

```
                for j in daysOfWeek do
                    match j with
                    | DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek -> // this does not work
                        let order =
                            query{
                                for o in orders do
                                where(o.NOTHING = i.Works) // NO dot intellisense on o
                            }
```

I suspect this may have something to do with the nesting.  How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching can only test equality with constants, not values such as `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek`. The reason is that it would make it ambiguous when the value is a simple variable name, because variables in a pattern are used to bind whatever value is at this position to a name, rather than comparing it to an existing variable:

```
match j with
| x ->
    // in here, x is equal to j.
```

In your specific case, you can just use `if`:

```
for j in daysOfWeek do
    if j = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek then
        let order = // ...
```

But if, in a more complex case, you want to compare with an inner pattern, you can use a [guard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx):

```
match someRecord with
| { someField = d } when d = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek ->
    let order = // ...
```